# Syncing canvas drawing / reading

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, canvas

So I have this little static class which does some image transformation:

```
// static class ImageFactory
var ImageFactory = (function () {

    var ImageFactory = {};

    ImageFactory.flip = function (image) {
        return invert(image, false, true);
    };

    ImageFactory.mirror = function (image) {
        return invert(image, true, false);
    };

    // private
    function invert(image, isMirror, isFlip) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.translate(isMirror ? canvas.width : 0, isFlip ? canvas.height : 0);
        context.scale(isMirror ? -1 : 1, isFlip ? - 1 : 1);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        return canvas;
    }

    return ImageFactory;

})();
```

The problem is: sometimes it produces 'blank' (wholly transparent) images instead of flips and mirrors, both in Chrome and Firefox. I suspect it has something to do with asynchronous operations which sometimes don't get done in time. According to some literature canvas drawing should be treated synchronously by browsers, but this issue tells me the other way.

Anyway, is there a safe way to draw to a secondary canvas and then use that canvas as an image to draw on the main canvas?

This is the code which should ensure no ImageFactory method is called before all input images are ready:

```
function load() {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        var image = images[i];

        if (!image.complete) {
            var timeout = setTimeout(onTimeout, LOADING_TIMEOUT);
            return;
        }
    }

    scene = sceneFactory();
    loop();

    function onTimeout() {
        load();
    }
}
```

Where `images` is just an array containing all images in the DOM. Only after `loop()` is called I have some calls to the ImageFactory methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure exactly what may cause the problem , but i guess it is caused by the image not being ready when the function gets called.

Try calling the image mirroring function after the image has finished loading.

Use image onload callback to check if image has finished loading and is ready to be used.

You may also try drawing the canvas again after a second or so, just to make sure it gets drawn properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Rainer. Well, I'm already calling the method after the input image is properly loaded, as you suggested. I also try to draw it again and again, but when the issue happens, the damage is permanent. So I believe the root of the problem is in the image transformation itself. I'll do some more testing and keep you posted if I find more clues. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using drawRect to draw a background for the canvas, and see if it gets a proper width/height position and is added to the dom correctly.

do you set image.onload before setting the src ?, in case image is already cached.
Does the image have valid dimensions ( echo out image width/height )

Comment: Edited the original question to add the code which ensures all input images are already loaded.

Comment: I found the bug. It was in my code, I was indeed calling some ImageFactory methods before ```loop()``` was called. Anyway, you were right about image loading, thanks a lot for your help!